# What are your references for understanding MVC?

Tags: java, c++, model-view-controller, oop, software-design

I'm was searching for a standard reference to understand MVC, i mean as book. I have some idea of this architecture learned from the reference implementation of Java Swing components like JTable. However, i'm after a core understanding on MVC. Kindly give pointers.

I don't understand, why this question is given -ve markings. I was just asking for Standard Reference like "Design Patterns by the Gang of Four". I have done enough homework with wrt MVC. Here, i'm actually seeking a professional reference book. or good pointers.

It is easy to learn from random links, however those pointers should have good weight like the author who wrote it, these kind of information can only be obtained from experienced people like you. Please don't discourage by marking these question -ve.

Comment: Have you tried googling this? http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/mvc-for-noobs/

Comment: Martin Fowler made an excelent study on this topic. Check out his article "Supervising Controller" http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html

Comment: SeanNieuwoudt and schoetbi i'm checking these links. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt has excellent implementation, documentation, and [introduction](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html) to Model/View Programming.

Comment: Excellent!! Igor OKs thanks. Its seems to explain well.

Answer (score 2):

Start from here [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) .

Comment: I don't understand, why this question is given -ve markings. I was just asking for Standard Reference like Design Patterns by the Gang of Four. I have done enough homework with wrt MVC. Here, i'm actually seeking a professional reference book. or good pointers. It is easy to learn from random links, however those pointers should have good weight like the author who wrote it, these kind of information can only be obtained from experienced people like you. Please don't discourage by marking these question -ve.

Comment: I did not do negative vote. I guess it was done by standard SO zealots who do not like people who are lazy...

Comment: to be honest i didn't meant you. Well, i got tired of  obvious link to Wikipedia, felt a thought it was an indirect insult, however. Btw, thanks for your response :)

Comment: Anyways, after you are done reading about MVC, I suggest you try the MVP and MGM patterns too. I like the MGM pattern the most (of all three mentioned here).

Comment: ah! this was exactly the kind of information i was pinging for. DejanLekic, thanks. I'm looking towards getting an overview of MVP and MGM.